# Why does strtof always output 0.0000?

Tags: c, string, floating-point

Calling `strtof` with a floating point number runs fine on my local machine but on the school's servers strtof always returns `0.000000`. I checked to see if there was anything stored in `errno` since a 0 should mean an error, but it says success. Does anyone have an idea why this might be?

Here is the code.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    printf("%f\n", strtof(argv[1],0));
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You should give us a simple, working example of code that you've compiled and run on both machines, and their output, so we can help.

Comment: @Lucas: there's no `strtof()` in there. Typo?

Comment: Sorry now it's there. Just tested on both machines, comes out as 0.000000 all the time on school server.

Comment: Have you compiled with `-Wall`? On my box, `strtof()` isn't defined unless you've got `_XOPEN_SOURCE=600` or `_ISOC99_SOURCE` defined. `-Wall` would warn you about that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Short version: compile with `-std=gnu99` or `-std=c99`. Explanation follows.

I've reproduced a similar "problem" on my own box. However, when I try to compile:

```
# gcc -Wall -o float float.c
float.c: In function 'main':
float.c:6: warning: implicit declaration of function 'strtof'
float.c:6: warning: format '%f' expects type 'double', but argument 2 has type 'int'
```

So I looked at the `man` page for `strtof()`, and it says:

```
SYNOPSIS
   #include <stdlib.h>

   double strtod(const char *nptr, char **endptr);

   #define _XOPEN_SOURCE=600   /* or #define _ISOC99_SOURCE */
   #include <stdlib.h>

   float strtof(const char *nptr, char **endptr);
   long double strtold(const char *nptr, char **endptr);
```

What that means is that one of those values has to be `#define`d before including `stdlib.h`. However, I just recompiled with `-std=gnu99`, and that defines one of those for me and it works.

```
# gcc -std=gnu99 -Wall -o float float.c
# ./float 2.3
2.300000
```

Moral: always compile with `-Wall`. ;-)

Comment: Interesting. Does this mean that the "default" compiler on my school's machines are neither one of these? Was another strtof being called?

Comment: @Lucas: I believe the defaults `gcc` compiles with vary based on the system. Maybe the OS, I'm not sure; someone else might be able to shed some more light. But the compiler (if you're using `gcc` on the command line) is still `gcc`, it's just using different standards in deciding how to compile your program. You can look here for some basic info: http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Standards.html

Comment: `-Wall -Werror`, or you'll miss the warnings (especially if there are many files).

Comment: @Lucas: It calls the same `strtof` function either way, but without `-std=c99` it calls it incorrectly because it can't see the declaration.

Answer (score 2):

Have you included the header where strtof is defined (stdlib.h), otherwise you may get 0.0 since by default unknown functions in C are treated as returning int.